# Why can I use a service without importing its provider module?

Tags: angular, service, module, lazy-loading

I am trying to work myself into how multiple NgModules in an angular application work together, especially I am trying to understand how to properly import a `SharedModule` that provides commonly used services, into lazily loaded feature modules.

Step by step:

- I create a new angular app: `ng new playground --routing`
- I create a `SharedModule` which is meant to provide services and commonly used declarables: `ng generate module shared`
- I create a service inside the shared module: `ng generate service shared/foo`
- Now I have a `FooService` inside my `SharedModule`'s directory, but I want the service to be provided by the `SharedModule`. So, I change the `@Injectable` annotation to:

  ```
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: SharedModule
  })
  ```
- Because I want to keep my `AppModule` and its service injector as clean as possible (in the real world later, I will also be using a `CoreModule` but that's not the scope of my question so let's get back on track)
- Now, I want to add a new feature, so I generate a new FeatureModule that I want to load lazily: `ng generate module feature --routing`
- Now, I have a `FeatureModule`
- Let's lazy-load the feature module by adding a route to the `AppRoutingModule`:

  ```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'feature',
      loadChildren: './feature/feature.module#FeatureModule'
    }
  ];
  ```
- I assume that somewhere in the `AppModule`'s template, I have a `<router-outlet>` and a `routerLink` that navigates to `/feature`.
- In the `FeatureModule`, we still have to generate a component that we want to show when navigating there: `ng generate component feature/start`
- To make my new `StartComponent` the initial component that is showed when routing to my `FeatureModule`, I will adjust the routes in the `FeatureRoutingModule`:

  ```
  const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: StartComponent
  }];
  ```
- Now, I want to use my `FooService`, that I added to the `SharedModule`, inside my `StartComponent`. So I inject it there.

  ```
  export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private foo: FooService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
  ```
- `ng serve`
- Navigate to the `FeatureModule` and see a runtime error! That's what I expected, because I did not import the `SharedModule` in the `FeatureModule`, so the injector does not know the `FooService`.
- So far so good, let's now come to the main point of my question:
- I will create one more module, that is not lazily loaded, which is going to be the `CoreModule`. To keep the `AppModule` as clean and as small as possible, I will implement the initial app in the `CoreModule`. `ng generate module core`
- Of course we also need some component in the `CoreModule`: `ng generate component core/core-main`
- Now, I also want to use the `FooService` in my new `CoreMainComponent`. So, let's also inject it there:

  ```
  export class CoreMainComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private foo: FooService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
  ```
- This time I will not forget to import the `SharedModule` inside my `CoreModule`. But remember I still forgot and did not import `SharedModule` in `FeatureModule`. Of course I have to use the `CoreMainComponent` somewhere, so I export it. So this is the new `CoreModule` decoration:

  ```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [CoreMainComponent],
    exports: [CoreMainComponent]
  })
  export class CoreModule { }
  ```
- Also import the `CoreModule` into the `AppModule` and add an `<app-core-main></app-core-main>` in the AppModule's template.
- `ng serve`
- My expectation: As soon as I click the link to lazily load and navigate to my `FeatureModule`, I would still expect a runtime error. The `CoreModule` imports the `SharedModule`, but the `FeatureModule` doesn't. But in both modules, the `FooService` is used.
- In fact, it works. I can use the component from the feature module without any errors. So the injector seems to know the `FooService` even in the `FeatureModule`, although I did not import it there. I would have expected it to fail
- Can someone help me out to understand why this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to work, whenever you import any **non-lazy-loaded module** in your `AppModule` then the services of that **non-lazy loaded module** are available throughout the app.
The reason besides this, ***in Angular Parent and child module, share the same Injector!***. But in the case of the `FeatureModule` (**lazy loaded module**), they have their own injector so any service provided in the lazy loaded module is only available to that module. 
In your case, you can say that `CoreModule` is a child module for the `AppModule` and in turns `SharedModule` is a child of `CoreModule` since both are **non-lazy loaded module** that's why your `FooService` is available in `FeatureModule` automatically.